# How to change the theme in an Ace editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I've been trying to add syntax highlighting to my web app and found ace. However, after working at the solution provided in the documentation, I am still unable to change the editor theme. Does anyone know how to go about this?

So far I've just initialized the element with the following code

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
editor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
editor.setTheme('ace-builds-master/theme/tomorrow_night.css');
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: @YuliaV So far I've just initialized the element with the following code `var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
editor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
editor.setTheme('ace-builds-master/theme/tomorrow_night.css');
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");`

Comment: @user3785038 where did you find the snippet which passes `tomorrow_night.css` to setTheme? Also could you please move the  code snippet from your comment into the question.

Comment: I added the code to the question since OP didn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the build mode argument to `setTheme()` is not a path but an id of the theme so you need to call 
`.setTheme('ace/theme/tomorrow_night')` instead

Note that you also can set all the options in one call using

```
editor.setOptions({
    useWrapMode: true,
    highlightActiveLine: true,
    showPrintMargin: false,
    theme: 'ace/theme/tomorrow_night',
    mode: 'ace/mode/javascript'
})
```

or in newer version of ace pass object with options to ace.edit

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor"{
    useWrapMode: true,
    ...
})
```

Comment: couldnt find the setOptions method in the editor.js or edit_session.js file in the src, where exactly is this method

Comment: @PirateApp `var editor = ace.edit("editor");` - is that what you mean?